# How to get custom data in a combo box

Tags: javascript, rally

I am trying to populate a combobox with a list of Project names.  I am able to successfully get all Project names, but I cannot seem to figure out how to add them as a custom set of data to a combobox.  I have looked into using the other types of comboboxes (Iteration, Portfolio, Attribute, etc), but they don't seem to have the capabilities to add custom data to their drop down list (unless I am mistaken).  Here is the code that I am using for my combo box:

```
this.down = this.add({
    xtype: 'rallycombobox',
    storeConfig: [{
        model: 'Project',
        autoLoad: true,
        fieldLabel: 'Projects:',
        data: this.project_names,
        width: field_width
    }]
});
```

When trying to run with this code, I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined.  I cannot figure out how to get it to work.  I have also tried it with the following:

```
this.down = this.add({
    xtype: 'rallycombobox',
    model: 'Project',
    fieldLabel: 'Projects:',
    data: this.project_names,
    width: field_width
});
```

I still end up with the same error.  Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list of Projects in hand that you'd like to use in a ComboBox, instead of a [Rally ComboBox](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox) I'd recommend just using the [Ext ComboBox](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox). The Rally ComboBox is designed to populate its store by querying the data from rally - thus the `getProxy`error you are seeing when trying to mix and match the Rally WSAPI store with local data.

The setup might look something like the following.

```
// The data store containing the list of Projects
var projectStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['_ref', 'Name'],
    data : [
        {"_ref": "/project/12345678910", "Name": "Project 1"},
        {"_ref": "/project/12345678911", "Name": "Project 2"},
        {"_ref": "/project/12345678912", "Name": "Project 3"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the Projects data store
this.projectSelector = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose Project',
    store: projectStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'Name',
    valueField: '_ref',
    listeners:{
         scope: this,
         select: function(combobox) {
            // Do stuff here
            console.log('Ref of Project Selected: ' + this.projectSelector.getValue());

        }
    }
});

this.down('#projectSelectorContainer').add(this.projectSelector);
```

Hopefully this is helpful. Let us know if there's follow-on questions.

Comment: is it possible to get a list of all projects inside the current project that I am in (in Rally) in the `data` field while creating the data store?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    //Write app code here

    var projectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
        model: 'project',
        fetch: ['Name','ObjectID'],
        autoLoad: true,
        // filters:[{
            // property:'ObjectID',
            // operator:'=',
            // value: __PROJECT_OID__
        // }],


        listeners:{
            load: function(store,records,success){
                this._updateCombo(store);
            },
            scope: this

        }



    });
    console.log('/project/',__PROJECT_OID__);
},

_loadCombo: function(myStore){

    this._myCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
        fieldLabel: 'Choose Project',
        store: myStore,
        queryMode: 'remote',
        displayField: 'Name',
        valueField: 'Name',
        listeners: {
            select: function(combobox,records){
                console.log(records[0]["data"]["Name"]);
            }
        },
        scope:this

    });
    this.add(this._myCombo);

},
_updateCombo: function(myStore){
    if(this._myCombo === undefined){
        this._loadCombo(myStore);
    }else{
        this._myCombo.clearValue();
    }

}

});
```